# How to detect whether or not user is clicking inside Circle in python graphics window

Tags: graphics, python-3.x

In my program I have three circles drawn in the graphics window, and I need different responses to occur depending on which one the user clicks on.

```
    cup1 = Circle(Point(35,100),25)
    cup1.draw(win)
    cup2 = cup1.clone()
    cup2.move(65,0)
    cup2.draw(win)
    cup3 = cup1.clone()
    cup3.move(130,0)
    cup3.draw(win)
```

So I need something that would work like this:

```
    userchoice = win.getMouse()
    cup1choice = False
    cup2choice = False
    cup3choice = False
    if userchoice in cup1:
        cup1choice = True
    if userchoice in cup2:
        cup2choice = True
    if userchoice in cup3:
        cup3choice = True
```

But I realize that a Circle is not iterable like that, so I'm looking for some other kind of method to determine whether the user is clicking inside cup 1, 2, or 3. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the centre and radius of each `Circle`, you could write a function to determine whether a given `Point` is within that as follows:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_within(point, circle):
    distance = sqrt(((point.x - circle.x) ** 2) + 
                    ((point.y - circle.y) ** 2))
    return distance < circle.radius
```

Note that you will have to tweak the attribute names according to the graphics library you are using.